# std::string is totally crashing in msvcp90d.dll

Tags: c++, dll, crash, std, stdstring

The library is using std::string. When some specific application is linked with it, the string operations performed in library are getting totally crashy.

For instance the string assignment operator '=' (stack trace is attached).

[image]

The destination of memcpy_s( ... ) and size are looking quite scrambled.

We can not repro it locally. Please advice.

Edit:
code is looking like this:

```
...
#define DEFAULT_VAL "value"
...
class MyClass {
public:
 MyClass(const std::string& s=DEFAULT_VAL)
 {
  _test() = s;
 }
protected:
 inline const std::string& test() const {return m_test;}
 inline std::string& _test() {return m_test;}
private:
 std::string m_test;
};

....
MyClass c;
```

Comment: This looks like memory corruption due to an access out of bounds, smashing the stack, access after free, double free, or the like. `valgrind` (or a similar tool) is your friend.

Comment: 0xCD is a clean memory filler in Microsoft debug heap. So my guess is your application is using an uninitialized object somewhere.

Comment: Sharing the code block exhibiting the error might assist in debugging. Just sayin'

Comment: Why are you running a debug build at the customer site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in a case of a DLL exposing `std::string` at the interface, make sure that both the .EXE and the .DLL are built with the *same* compiler version and the *same* flavor of the CRT (e.g. both debug, both release, both with the same settings of `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING`, etc.).

Answer (score 4):

You are probably initializing a `std::string` (or `std::wstring`) with 0, most likely via  a nullpointer, like…

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s1( 0 );
    string s2 = s1;
}
```

Don’t do that.

There aren’t many other ways to make `std::string` “crashy”, so chances are that this is it. Now go debugging! Good luck!

Comment: It happens on customer's machine and we can't reproduce it. Can it be crt mismatch?

Comment: @Cheers: According to the screenshot in the question and the question title itself (mentioning msvcp90**d**.dll), the OP is using the debug version of the CRT. And (at least with VS2010), if you try to initialize a `std::string` with `0`/`nullptr`, you get an error message box with a **"Debug Assertion Failed!"** message, and proper **"Expression: invalid null pointer"** text. I think the actual problem may be a mismatch in CRT versions/flavors used by the EXE and the DLL.

Comment: He says if he is linking with our /MDd lib its working well. But getting crashes with our /MD lib.

Comment: Cool, I was able to repro the crash when linking with /MDd test application.

Comment: @ActivationCloud: So is this a problem of mismatch between debug/release builds? /MDd dynamically links with the debug version of CRT DLLs, while /MD dynamically links to the release version.